# manipulating SWR data with local data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, swr

I have an API with SWR that returns data something like this:

```
const {data: data, error: error} = useSWR('fetchData', fetcher, { refreshInterval: 5000 })
```

I want to display the status of my data `data.status` which is easy:

```
<p>{data.status}</P>
<button onClick={changeStatus}>change status</button>
```

but there are sometimes that I need to manually change what needs to be displayed, for that I tried to store `data.status` to a variable first and then change it using two things:

```
if (data){
    status = data.status
}
const changeStatus = () => {
    status = 'bad'
}
```

which simply doesn't change status AND

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState('');
if (data){
    setStatus(data.status)
}
const changeStatus = () => {
    setStatus('bad')
}
```

which gives me "too many iterations" error!

So how can I manually change the data I get from SWR in a way that it still calls the api every 5 seconds and update the data accordingly?

Comment: After we set the status to `bad`, when the API calls again in 5 seconds, do you want it to override `bad`?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot set it like that. you need to use ***useEffect*** if you want to store status in a state

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    setStatus(data.status);
  }
}, [data])
```